# ActiveRecord get all model records plus those matching some criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to create a set of checkbox tags in order the user can see how much of them he has (has subscribed to), and to which no.

My models are User, Category and Preferences which handles the has_many through relationship between both first models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :preferences
  has_many :categories, through: :preferences
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :preferences
  has_many :users, through: :preferences
end

class Preference < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

The goal is to get all the categories existent and to be able a extra way to check if the user has such categories, this way I can use an active CSS rule and show them different to those which the user doesn't have.

I've tried just getting all the categories name, and also all the categories name for those corresponding to the user and joining them as one array with multiple 2 elements arrays inside and I get something like:

```
[
  ["coffee",         "coffee"],
  ["coworking",      "food"],
  ["event",          "pub"],
  ["food",           "restaurant"],
  ["landmark",       "shop"],
  ["nightlife",      "vacation"],
  ["pub",            nil],
  ["restaurant",     nil],
  ["shop",           nil],
  ["transportation", nil],
  ["vacation",       nil]
]
```

This way would be good if I can make them match in name, since the names won't never be repeated for each array, maybe like:

```
[
  ["coffee",         "coffee"],
  ["coworking",      nil],
  ["event",          nil],
  ["food",           "food"],
  ["landmark",       nil],
  ["nightlife",      nil],
  ["pub",            "pub"],
  ["restaurant",     "restaurant"],
  ["shop",           "shop"],
  ["transportation", nil],
  ["vacation",       "vacation"],
]
```

So I can see which of those are nil in the last (second) element in the array and don't print the CSS rule for checked elements.

But it seems I need to do it outside an ActiveRecord query.

Does it exist any way to get the desired result by using ActiveRecord, or do I have to handle it manually, or to change the schema?

Comment: I'm no SQL expert, but that sounds like a [`left_outer_joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) sql query, wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a few steps.

First get all categories

```
all_categories = Category.all
```

Then get the user categories (I'm assumiming you already have code to define `current_user` for the request)

```
@user_categories = current_user.categories
```

Then you can find the difference between the two:

```
@non_user_categories = all_categories - @user_categories
```

The `@user_categories` and `all_categories` are not, strictly speaking, Arrays - they are `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. But you can still use array subtraction to find the difference. Note that `@non_user_categories` *is* an actual Array.

---

You can do it another way which avoids loading excess records, though for a small data set the performance gain will be inconsequential.

```
@user_categories = current_user.categories

@non_user_categories = Category.joins(:preferences).where.not(
  "preferences.user_id = ?",
  current_user.id
)
```

Comment: I've tried `@user_categories = Category.joins(:preferences).where(preferences: { user_id: id })` for getting the user_categories, I don't know why but using `where.not` it doesn't show the non-user categories, just an empty query result.